# Permutation with exactly one pair of inverse order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I came up with an elementary counting problem for which I could find a simple solution. Please help.

N people of different heights line up single-file, in how many ways there is
exactly one person standing immediately behind someone who is taller?

Comment: Did you try anything, simple or complex ? Where did you face a problem ? Let us know so that we can better help.

Comment: Hint: First arrange them in single file from tallest to shortest, and ponder a bit

Comment: Many thanks. I tried some small cases of n, but I do not know how to generalize. I also thought first sorting them, and then swapping a pair, but still not quite clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848339/the-number-of-permutations-of-1-2-ldots-n-that-have-exactly-one-ascent-r

Comment: Indeed. Many thanks. @KevinLong